# Offer playable windows to other websites

Tags: embed

first of all sorry for the vague question, I am very unsure of the terms I should use in english for what I am trying to acomplish. So don't know where to start looking for.

I have a website about a card game (Bridge), based on mysql, php, html5 and javascript, with AJAX calls. (www.bridgegod.com)

I would like to provide support for people who write articles about the game on Blogs or the like to make their articles interactive by displaying a window on their website where my website shows up on the playing page, so the game would be playable there as it is on my site.

So basically one window on their website would actually show mine.

I don't know where to start, I don't even know what to look for, is embeding the right word for what I am looking for?, will they need a copy of my js files?, or database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use an iFrame:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp